# Vue.js как подключить стороннюю библиотеку materializecss?

Tags: vue.js, materialize-css

хочу использовать в своем проекте библиотеку [materializecss](https://materializecss.com) не vue-material

Можно подключить её в индекс файле так:

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Ну насколько я понял это не правильный подход, хотя почему не понял, можете тоже внести ясность.

Можно установив через npm и создав плагин:

./src/plugins/materializecss.js

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```

./src/main.js

```
// Тут я пробовал и так ...
import '@/plugins/materializecss'

// ... и так
import M from 'materialize-css' 
Vue.use(M)
```

и так как в [этой](https://alligator.io/vuejs/css-frameworks-vuejs/) статье

```
import './../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
import './../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import './../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
```

как итог стили есть, а вот js не работает.

./src/App.vue  Вставляем dropdown

```
<template>
  ...
  <div>
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
      <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  ....
</template>
```

Как правильно подключать такие сторонние библиотеки / фреймворки ?

Comment: Возможно вам будет интересно, что кроме vue-material существует [`vuetify`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключать в index.html вам никто не запрещает. Все примеры подключений сторонних модулей в принципе верны.
Например, когда я создавал проект и использовал vue-loader(на основе Webpack), то выполнялось это так на примере другой библиотеки:

1) npm i axios

2)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Axios from 'axios'

//используем подключенную библиотеку
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
```

В вашем случае это работать не должно так как materializecss это не плагин Vue

```
// ... и так
import M from 'materialize-css' 
Vue.use(M)
```

Установил вашу библиотеку и подключил таким образом

```
import "materialize-css";
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```

И как оказалось, все прекрасно работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше разбираться я не стал, похоже вам следует тщательнее изучить API библиотеки.